# Performing SQL queries on basic Excel 2013 worksheet as table using ADO with VBA triggers Errors

Tags: sql, excel, adodb, recordset, vba

I'm developping modules on a client XLSm with 32-bits 2013 Excel.

I'd like to use datas on worksheet as if it is an Access table.

With a lot of difficulties, I think connection is now OK.

Still, I have error : 3001 Arguments are of wrong type, are out of acceptable range. Error that I cannot understand.

Here excerpts of VBA lines :

In addition, I added 20 lines in data Worksheet below the header line to permit to Excel to interpret for the type of each columns.

```
    varCnxStr = "Data Source=" & G_sWBookREINVOICingFilePath & ";" &   "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=15';"

    With conXLdb
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Mode = adModeShareExclusive
        .Open varCnxStr
    End With

    strSQL = "SELECT * "
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [ReInvoiceDB$B2B5072] inum "
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE inum.InvoiceNum LIKE '1712*' "
    strSQL = strSQL & ";"

    '>> TRIGGERs ERROR with the current Where Clause !!'
    adoXLrst.Open strSQL, conXLdb, dbOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    If adoXLrst.BOF And adoXLrst.EOF Then
        'no records returned'
        GoTo Veloma
    End If

    adoXLrst.MoveFirst

    Do While Not adoXLrst.EOF
        'Doing stuff with row'
        adoXLrst.MoveNext
    Loop

    sHighestSoFar = adoXLrst(1).Value '> just to try for RecordSet : Codes are not completed...

    sPrefixeCURR = Mid(sHighestSoFar, 1, 4)
    Highest = CInt(Mid(sHighestSoFar, 5))

    '> Increment >'
    Highest = Highest + 1

    HighestStr = sPrefixeCURR & Format(Highest, "00")

    strGSFNumber = HighestStr

    adoXLrst.Close
    conXLdb.Close

Veloma: 
    On Error Resume Next
    Set adoXLrst = Nothing
    Set conXLdb = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

Etc.

Any idea about what seems be wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: What line are you receiving that error on?

Comment: Your second query has two `FROM` and two `WHERE`. You need to learn basic query syntax. You already have the result query `Debug.Print strSQL` try it direct on the db first.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I believe those lines are commented out. I've edited out the commented lines and indented uniformly.

Comment: @JNevill You are right. Then would be easier if OP just show us the strSQL result to see what is wrong with the query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza assuming it's the query that's failing. I have an assumption that the line `adoXLrst.Open strSQL, conXLdb, dbOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText` is failing, but I'm hesitant to dig in without confirmation from OP about which line is causing the error to be thrown.

Comment: Actually.. now that I look at it, @botakelymg, `dbOpenDynamic` is not a constant that is available in ADODB. I believe that should be `adOpenDynamic` and that would definitely throw that error since it's expecting a `CursorTypeEnum` and you are supplying it with a `variant` set to `nothing`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, @botakelymg, are you using the Tools>>Reference to bring in the ADODB library, or are you using late binding? If you are using Early Binding then it should prompt you with a list of choices for the `CursorTypeEnum` as you are typing the code which helps avoid this type of error.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you for having removed the comments out. 
You're right : adoXLrst.Open strSQL, conXLdb, dbOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText code is failing on this Worksheet data.
It's my 1st time using Excel as if it is an Access table with ADO but I'm very good for Access and its SQL statements. Here the exercise is just how to pull out datas and put them in Cursor

Comment: @JNevill the reference to ADO 6.x is set for sure. So it's under Early binding.
The debugging mode shows that the Recordset object is set but adoXLrst.BOF And adoXLrst.EOF  are True so I cannot ask for looping.

    adoXLrst.Open strSQL, conXLdb, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText 

is the actual statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an old example I have been using successfully. Note that the sheet name in the book are Sheet1 and Sheet2, but in the query I had to use sheet1$ and sheet2$. I noticed you had $ signs in the middle of your sheet names. perhaps that's the issue ?

```
Sub SQLUpdateExample()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
           "DriverId=790;" & _
           "Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
           "DefaultDir=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";ReadOnly=False;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = con.Execute("UPDATE [Sheet1$]  inner join [Sheet2$] on [Sheet1$].test1 = [Sheet2$].test1  SET [Sheet1$].test3 = [Sheet2$].test2 ")

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: after some searches on the Net the syntax has changed for Excel 2013 and this statement is expected to function for Column B from line 2 to 5072 for example.
I'v changed for [ReInvoiceDB$] so there is no error but the Cursor seems to be empty. Both BOF and EOF are True...

Answer (score 0):

To give more details about the whole module to be implemented : it is to perform a Transaction unit.

This transaction will comprise 3 operations : get a max value from a column (Invoice number) to increment it, record the new number inside an Access table (by DAO), the same Excel file (by ADO) and generating document on HDD.

So it is aimed to use the Excel file as a table not as a file manipulated with Windows script or Excel VBA. My end user is disturbed by the pop-uping of an Excel opening file operation. As a developer, I'm feeling more comfortable with using SQL statements as much as possible inside Transaction session. Is that your opinion too ?